# Comparing columns per row in a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataframe with 3 columns and a few thousand rows. Now I want to compare the values in the columns per row, to see if the values follow a particular trend.

```
Df <- data.frame(Value1 = c(13,19,56,47,15,13,64, 48), Value2 = c(54,64,11,21,15,48,12,78), Value3 = c(66,78,05,12,21,23,45,30))
```

In this example dataframe row 1 would be an upward slope and row 3 would be an downward slope.

I wrote this for loop to go through the whole dataframe.

```
for(row in 1:nrow(Df)) {
  if (Df$Value1 > Df$Value2 & Df$Value2 > Df$Value3){
    print("Downward slope")
  } else if (Df$Value1 < Df$Value2 & Df$Value2 < Df$Value3){
    print("Upward slope")
  } else if (Df$Value1 > Df$Value2 & Df$Value2 < Df$Value3){
    print("Dip")
  } else if (Df$Value1 < Df$Value2 & Df$Value2 > Df$Value3){
    print("Peak")
  }
}
```

Now this is already pretty inefficient probably, but it doesn't even work. When running this I get the error:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedthe condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used[1] "Upward slope"
>
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used[1] "Upward slope"

How would I get something like this to work?

Comment: You are not using `row` anywhere inside the `for` loop. For example, change first `if` to `if (Df$Value1[row] > Df$Value2[row] & Df$Value2[row] > Df$Value3[row])` and similarly for other `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best to use vectorised `ifelse` rather than a loop

```
ifelse(Df[,1] >  Df[,2],
  ifelse(Df[,2] >  Df[,3], 'down', 'dip'),
  ifelse(Df[,2] >  Df[,3], 'peak', 'up'))
#[1] "up"   "up"   "down" "down" "up"   "peak" "dip"  "peak"
```